# How would you interpret this scatter plot?

Tags: pandas, statistics, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am graphing some data from a movie data base.  I made a graph of average user vote vs. budget.  The x axis is in $100,000,000.  To me it looks like there is a positive correlation between budget and rating on budgets over $100,000,000.  The problem I see is that there are too many data points between 0 and 100,000,000 that are all over the place.  I am doing this data analysis via pandas as I learn statistics and pandas.  Any suggestions on how to clean this data further?

[image]

Comment: Might look better with a log scale for the x-axis

Comment: Perhaps you could make the data-points smaller? That could reveal some structure in the dense region to the left.